# Java error message when importing a package using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm writing some code and I'm getting errors on four different lines saying that packages don't exist. The errors are on lines 7 to 10, which say package org.web3d.x3d.sai does not exist. The code that I have for this project is:

```
package xj3dtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.Browser;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DComponent;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DScene;

public class Xj3DTest extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DTest(String title) {

        super(title);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        X3DComponent x3dComponent = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(null);

        Browser browser = x3dComponent.getBrowser();

        Component browserComponent = (Component)  x3dComponent.getImplementation();

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add(browserComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[]   {"test.x3dv"});

        browser.replaceWorld(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xj3DTest frame = new Xj3DTest("Xj3D test");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And the code for the test.x3dv is:

```
#X3D V3.0 utf8

PROFILE Interactive

DEF TS TimeSensor {
  cycleInterval 3
  loop TRUE
}

DEF TG Transform {
  rotation 0 1 0 0
  children Shape {
    geometry Box {}
    appearance Appearance {
      material DEF MAT Material {
        diffuseColor 1 0 0
      }
    }
  }
}

DEF OI OrientationInterpolator {
  key [ 0 0.5 1 ]
  keyValue [
     0 1 0 0
     0 1 0 3.14
     0 1 0 6.28
  ]
}

ROUTE TS.fraction_changed TO OI.set_fraction 
ROUTE OI.value_changed TO TG.rotation
```

The reason why I'm making this little project is because I need to display .x3d files through a Java project. I'm put `-Xmx450M -Djava.library.path='F:\Uni\Uni work\Year Three\xj3d-code-12559-trunk\bin'` in the project properties VM option and have put all the `x3d jars` in a library called `Xj3D`. I've downloaded the `org.web3d.x3d.sai` by doing a Google search and going on the first link, and I've put it in the JARS lib folder that I've made in Netbeans. But I'm still getting the errors.

I am aware that I asked the same question yesterday, but found that it wasn't properly formatted and I felt like it didn't convey what I wanted clearly.

**EDIT**

When I run the code now, after getting the correct JARS in the library, is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at  org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(BrowserFactory.java:252)
at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.<init>(Xj3DTest.java:20)
at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.main(Xj3DTest.java:36)
```

Comment: Does this package exists in the jar file you've downloaded?

Comment: I've downloaded the jar file and I have the current Xj3D code trunk folder with the other jars. I'm unsure on how to check if a package exists in a jar file.

Comment: **EDIT** I've looked in the `xj3d-sai_2.0.0.jar` file and there are `org.web3d.x3d.sai.Browser.class` `org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory.class` `org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DComponent.class` and `org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DScene.class`

Comment: I executed your program in netbeans, while adding the jar downloaded at [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxj3dsaijar.htm) into Libraries, and it gave me an NotSupportedException while running, but not such errors as yours about package not existing.

Comment: Thanks, I've just modified the libraries so it's just that one jar in it and the errors have gone! But I'm getting the same problem while running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you must include in your buildpath all jars listed [here](http://www.xj3d.org/tutorials/xj3d_application.html).

Comment: So place those jars in the list in the library that I created in Netbeans?

Comment: Go to Libraries->Add Jar/Folder  for each of them, after downloading.

Comment: I've just done that. And the following came up when I ran it: `Unable to find X3D browser factory implementation` and `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: NullPointerException is triggered because of this line`x3dComponent.getImplementation();` You're trying to call a method on a null object.  I think you better start a new question thread, maybe there are some more knowledgeable folk about x3d out there. Also if I was of any help, please mark my answer accepted.

Comment: So the `x3dComponent.getImplementation();` line is a null object? I'm going to start a new question thread to see if other people may know how to sort this last bit out! Thanks :)

Comment: I've made another question thread and I could be getting that because of the `X3DComponent x3dComponent = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(null);` line.